# How to decode json into a Codable to use in a SwiftUI Preview?

Tags: ios, swiftui, codable

Wondering if there is a way to decode some json into a Codable that is a dependency of a  View so i can use swiftUI previews?

Here is a working unit test for the codable

```swift
    func testDecode() {
        let data = Data(jsonProj.utf8)
        //frmt
        let frmt2 = DateFormatter()
        frmt2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
        //decoder
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ (decoder) -> Date in
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
            guard let d = frmt2.date(from: dateStr) else { fatalError() } //fixme some danger here
            return d
        })
        do {
            let p = try decoder.decode(Project.self, from: data)
            XCTAssertEqual(p.id, 2)
            print(p)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
```

I'd like to use it here

```swift
struct PreProjectCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {

   //static let decodedJson: Project ... NEED THIS PART

    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                PreProjectCell(project: <#Project#>)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension Project {
    static var preview: Self {
        let data = Data(jsonProj.utf8)
        //frmt
        let frmt2 = DateFormatter()
        frmt2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
        //decoder
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ (decoder) -> Date in
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
            guard let d = frmt2.date(from: dateStr) else { fatalError() } //fixme some danger here
            return d
        })
        return try! decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Then in your SwiftUI Preview you can do:

```
struct PreProjectCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                PreProjectCell(project: .preview)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice 1. very swift!